# How to optimize the updating of values in an ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java

I want to store all values of a certain variable in a dataset and the frequency for each of these values. To do so, I use an `ArrayList<String>` to store the values and an `ArrayList<Integer>` to store the frequencies (since I can't use `int`). The number of different values is unknown, that's why I use `ArrayList` and not `Array`.

Example (simplified) dataset:

```
a,b,c,d,b,d,a,c,b
```

The `ArrayList<String>` with values looks like: `{a,b,c,d}` and the `ArrayList<Integer>` with frequencies looks like: `{2,3,2,2}`.

To fill these `ArrayLists` I iterate over each record in the dataset, using the following code.

```
public void addObservation(String obs){
    if(values.size() == 0){// first value
        values.add(obs);
        frequencies.add(new Integer(1));
        return;//added
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i<values.size();i++){
            if(values.get(i).equals(obs)){
                frequencies.set(i, new Integer((int)frequencies.get(i)+1));
                return;//added
            }
        }
        // only gets here if value of obs is not found
        values.add(obs);
        frequencies.add(new Integer(1));
    }
}
```

However, since the datasets I will use this for can be very big, I want to optimize my code, and using `frequencies.set(i, new Integer((int)frequencies.get(i)+1));` does not seem very efficient.

That brings me to my question; how can I optimize the updating of the `Integer` values in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: "Does not seem very efficient" does not seem like you profiled it.

Comment: You should use a Map. But even with two lists, your code could be made much simpler by using indexOf instead of iterating yourself. The empty list case and the "value not in the list" cases could also be grouped together.

Comment: You are reimplementing a so called multiset. Try to find an implementation for it and use that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [`HashMap<String,Integer>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Create the HashMap like so

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Then your addObservation method will look like

```
public void addObservation(String obs) {
    if( hm.contains(obs) )
        hm.put( obs, hm.get(obs)+1 );
    else
        hm.put( obs, 1 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was so focused on using ArrayLists that I didn't figure out that there might be Classes that are more suited for this purpose.

Comment: +1, Very good and easy to understand. In addition, if you want to display the dataset in order; use TreeMap either.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HashMap or a Hashtable as tskzzy suggested. Depending on your needs I would also create an object that has the name, count as well as other metadata that you might need.

So the code would be something like:

```
Hashtable<String, FrequencyStatistics> statHash = new Hashtable<String, FrequencyStatistics>();
for (String value : values) {
    if (statHash.get(value) == null) {
        FrequencyStatistics newStat = new FrequencyStatistics(value);
        statHash.set(value, newStat);
    } else {
        statHash.get(value).incrementCount();
    }
}
```

Now, your FrequencyStatistics objects constructor would automatically set its inital count to 1, while the incrementCound() method would increment the count, and perform any other statistical calculations that you might require. This should also be more extensible in the future than storing a hash of the String with only its corresponding Integer.

Comment: Creating an object just for keeping the frequency count would be bit costly, I think.

Comment: Agreed, but that depends on the other requirements, and if there is the need for other statistical information to be generated as well.